# yii cwebuser two seperate login in admin and frontend session issue

Tags: php, yii

I have two different types of users including admin users that manage the site and customers. For this i have using cwebuser and define in config.php file.

```
<?php

'user'=>array(
     'class' => 'CWebUser',
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'loginUrl'=>array('admin/'),
        //'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        'stateKeyPrefix'    => 'admin_',
    ),

    'customer' => array(
       'class' => 'CWebUser',
        'loginUrl' => '/site/',
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        //'allowAutoLogin' => true,
        'stateKeyPrefix'    => 'frontend_',
    )

?>
```

The problem is that if we logged in admin panel and open the front end, it automatically fetch the admin users details and display in front end. both logins(admin and front end) are different. How to rectify the session problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think This Will usefull to You

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/41410-change-login-url-for-cwebuser-multi-object/page__p__197433__hl__LoginUrl#entry197433
```